# CMake Error install TARGETS given no LIBRARY DESTINATION for module target

Tags: c++, cmake, llvm

I'm trying to build an open-sourced project, and in the CMakeLists, it tries to add an llvm lib (add_llvm_library) which fails with: `install TARGETS given no LIBRARY DESTINATION for module target`. I'm not used to CMakefile writing, so I don't really understand what the problem is.

Here is CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

project(WaspHypervisor C CXX)


set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

# set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -Wextra")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-g -O3")



include_directories(./include/)

add_library(wasp SHARED
    src/Virtine.cpp
    src/Cache.cpp
    src/binding.cpp
    )


install(TARGETS wasp LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)
install(
        DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/
    DESTINATION include
    FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h*")




add_subdirectory(test/)


find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)
add_definitions(${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})
include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${LLVM_CMAKE_DIR}")
include(AddLLVM)


add_llvm_library(VirtinePass MODULE
    pass/pass.cpp
    pass/VirtineCompiler.cpp
    pass/command.cpp
    PLUGIN_TOOL
    opt
)
```

and the error output

```
...
-- Linker detection: GNU ld
CMake Error at /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/cmake/llvm/AddLLVM.cmake:642 (install):
  install TARGETS given no LIBRARY DESTINATION for module target
  "VirtinePass".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:42 (add_llvm_library)
```

Please, does anyone have an idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LLVM 6.0 the command `add_llvm_library` doesn't recognize MODULE option. The only options it recognized are SHARED and BUILDTREE_ONLY: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/release/6.x/llvm/cmake/modules/AddLLVM.cmake#L600

Support for MODULE option has been added only in LLVM 8.0: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/release/8.x/llvm/cmake/modules/AddLLVM.cmake#L619

Comment: Ok, @Tsyvarev, I see, and when I look at the Makefile file, it is even expecting llvm-10 though I have version 6.0. 
Thank you for this insight I will try installing a newer version, test it, and let you know if it resolves the problem.

Comment: Thanks  @Tsyvarev! Installing llvm-10 solved the issue.